# авторизация клиентов в телеграмм боте на библиотеке TeleBot с помощью Mango

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

есть код для регистрации и входа в тг бот

```
import telebot
from pymongo import MongoClient

tb = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

client = MongoClient()
db = client.first_db
users = db['users']

@tb.message_handler(commands=['start', 'go'])
def start_handler(message):
    msg = tb.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, отправь логин и пароль")
    tb.register_next_step_handler(msg, auth)


def auth(message):
    data = message.text.split() 

    check = users.find_one({ 
        'username': str(data[0]),
        'password': str(data[1]),
    })

    if check is None: 
        tb.send_message(message.chat.id, r'Неправильно введен логин\пароль')

    else: 
        msg = tb.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что будем делать?')
        tb.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_step_func)
```

не могу разобраться с user и  'username': str(data[0]),
'password': str(data[1]), он заходит в функцию но не выходит